# Use python request to convert bytes gzip to .wav?

Tags: python, api, audio, request, wav

```
r_api= requests.get(url = urll, headers = hederr, stream=True) 

request_data = r_api.content

print(request_data)
```

**I got gzip bytes as output/response and I want to convert it into .wav file.**

**I tried this code and it's converting the file to gzip wav not to .wav.**

```py
with open('myfile_1.wav', mode='bx') as f:
    f.write(request_data)
```

***gzip bytes***

> how to convert it to gzip bytes to .wav?

```
b'\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\xedXwP\x93\xdb\xb6\xff\x12\x8a\x91\xfa\xd1{\x08M\x10\x14BW\xdcB\x88\x01\x11\x14\x90"E\xc0\x04B$B$$t\x05BW\x8a\x14\x95*\x88\xc8Q\x01A\xe4\x88\x02j\xc4\xc6\x11\x10\xc5\x06\xa2\x80\x01D\x01[\x00=G,x?\x8e\xe7\xcc\xf5\xfaf\xde\xcc\x9d7\xf7\xcd\xfd\x83\xdfd\xcdZ\xfb[k\xaf\xbd\xd6nkO\xf0x<~\x07\xdex\x87\xb1\xa1\xe9N&\xf4\x9f\x012\x84\xa5\xa59\x0e\xe1\xc6\x96\xe6\xf8\x1f9~Q\xc4[\x9a\xe2 cSKKc\xbc\xa9\x99\xb9\xb19\x847636Y\xb4\xff\x0f\xc5\xf3/\x88bGRXH(\xa1\x14V\x1c\xe5\xff\xe0\xe7\xcfd\xfeN\n\xe1\xff\x05063\xb1\xb0\xb0\xc4\x9b[\x98[\xfe\x8b\xfc\x13\x14i\x91qLd\xf5\xcd\x16\x1btv8\xe3\xbb,\xd8\xc9\x08\x0f\x8fF>\x851\xa2C\xa8\x8b\xbaA?\xc6\xd4"A\x90\xc0$\x04\x89\nB(h\xf1\xf7O\xa0~\xf2\xfcS\x9b\xf0\xbf\x87\x8bF(\x8e\x11\x1c\xb9\xb8\n\x1a!\xd40\xd6\xdf\n\x065\xf2\x7f\xac\x8cAhp\x1c\xfb\x87aT\x16\x8d\x82\xc2\x19\x86\x94\xddTV8\x9dj\x18\x1d\xccb\xd3\xc3w#*\x1dz\x18;\x12\xe1j\x7f\x99\xcaQ)\x7f\xfa\xfb3\xba5\x86\xc6\x86\xc8>\x13\x18\x8cdQB\x91\xb6_d\xe8\x9f\xc9.\xfbg\xb2\x7f\xa7\x81$\xfcsn\xffV\xc2\x02Q\x0c*}q`\x1c\x83\xfa\xf3\x84\xaa#\xa6\xde\x7fo\x9aU?&\xcf\x0e\x8f\xda\xfd\xa3\x17w\xa4Mu@\xb2\x0c\x0b^\xf4\xa9\xc1\xa0\xef\xa6!\x02\xccf|\xf7\xf9\x17\xb4\xa9\xdf\xbf\xabRY\xc1\xb4\x1f\xa2\x13\x8bb\x85\xe1\xbe\xcb\xe8\tvd`\x18"\xdb\xb1#\xd9\xd4\x1fl\xcc\xd9\x14\x06\xeb\x87\xf6\xdf\x12\xbc\xc8\xd4\xbf\'%EElp8\xc4U\xea\xb7?\x8dp\xec\xc8\xc8\xbf\x17\x04\xfdW\xc7*\x84r\xbes\xb4\x032H\xfc\x0f\x01\xe6.\xf6Y\xa2%\xfa7I\x15\xd9GA\xd0w\xa0\xfe\xa2\xdc\xbf\xb8,;2(\xfc\x9f:\xb1r\xe4\x1c\xb7\xd0X\xc1\xc1\xd0\x12\x96\xb0\x84%,a\tK\xf8o\x87\xd4)\x06\xf2F\x07\x05\n\xf2\\Z\xdc(\x0f\xf5\xf2\x0c\x1f\xf9\xca\xf9\xc9\n8\xc4h\x17}\xd7\xb7/\xea;~\xd6G\xfb\xb2"\xa93W;\xed\xc2\xc7\xe6\xa4\x8c\xd1\x8b\xfd\xb9\xe5\xcc#\x08\x13\xf8\xfc\xf1!\x07\xf4M\xec\xd5 >^>~\xd3B\xb6\xff\xb1\xcb\xefk\x9e\xb3DE\xb6^\xd0\xd9^\xe3\xb9\xf9\x8e\xfb.> \x9d\xa2I/3\x97\x1a]\xd8\xb0j\xb8\xf0\xbc\xc8\x8d\xc3\xf3D+\xcfQ\xd4\xf8\xe3\xdd!E\x9f^\xf1\x81#\x9d\x83\x13.\x84\xfa\xde\xfa\x16*\x94B;\xee\xd1E\x9f\x96y\x04\x88\t4\x12=\xf8\xe6\xc2\x04@L\xdc\x11\xfdk\xa4\xa8\xeb\xdb\xc3n\n\xc3\xc7\x9bku\x8d)\xc6\x97\xc3%v\xbf\xeb\xbd\xa3\xa0\xf8\t\x07L\x18q\xca2w4\xdaI\xbb\n[\x0f\x98P\xda\xaa1\xbd\xca\x15ND\xd2 \xe589\xaf\x17\x02\xa4`\xaa*qU\x93\x0b\xbc[\xcb;\xe7Z\xad\xe6k\xbe\xd8\xb4\xfd\x94\xd5\x894Ht\xae\xc9\x81\x0f\xa4\xdb\xb5\xa2\xf0Y\xda#\xa8\x0e7\x96V\x9d#\xf7\xb5\x8d\x8c\xe4LA[\xa4\xe8-\x7f\xf30MD\xef\x8a\xc7\x91]4\x17P)\xd5[\x9f\xba\xea<\xc8\x95\xdf\xa3-R\xe7\x9b\x00\xa5<Q_M\xe4\x031\x1358\xc8DaA\xe0P\xf5\xd8\x8b4\xe3vW\xd2\xc1\x88\x08\x9eBNX\xd7\x85\x8d\x9f-\xf2\x81\xc4\xba\xbd\xb8@\x87\xda\xc83\xc5\xd5\xe6\xb9\x12\x114\xfa\xd1\x17\xf2\xab\xac\x83+\x9dZ.\xaf\xeb)`\x02c\xc9\x19\x8c\xf7\xd7\xf2\xca\xd2Z\x9d\xfb%\xdd\x03\xa6\xd9\xc9\xd7\x9cO6\x87u\xd4\xe3b\xb8)sx0\x98\\\x06\x9b\x87\xfb.l\xe2\xf4z\xef\xadD\x1f\x96\xab\x9d\xcd\xde\x923p\'\xfct\x91P\x8b)\x0c\x1c\xde\xf7{\x93\x1f\xed\xad\\\x9b\xc1\xe4\x0bJ\xbde\xb7\xa5W\xc67^\xb16k\xacq\xb4\xec[\x83\x03D\xa7T\x0c%\xf5\xbd\x91\x9a\xe1\x0c\xa9\xae\xec\x85\xb3\x939\xae\xb4\xad\xd9\xb7\xf2\xea\xf3`\xcc\x89J> Nk{S2G\x17d8\x11\xd2moo\x93\xca0\xdd\xadBB\xab\xb3r\xfc\x88\xb4\xb5\xeb\xfb\x80\x99W\x1c\x86b4Q)\xf8h.\xf7\x94\x88\x91\xc0\xc2\xdd\xb2\x8a\x1b\x9a\rU\xee\x8f\x19\x89\x1b\xbf\xe5\x03\xbd\x10*L1\x98J\xdc\x9a\xdcA\xea\x0e\xc8\xbe\x97\xfeL\x91*!\x83O?\xf6\xee\xe1\xfe\xd4\xa8*0f\x1b\xc1\x0c\x89X\x89UZ\x1ex\xect\xfe\xf4{L\x9e\xf6/\xaf\x13\xbb\x94\xc4\'\xbeE\x8d\xb6\xbb\x02i\xac\x16L\x1e\xc1\x02\xfd\x87\x0c\xe3\x06\xe5\xea\x03[\xd1\x8fju\xcb\x0c\xcfwf\x8a@\xa4T\x1e\x90w\xf0\xe3P\x8e\x9eN46\x90\xdb}\x9ds\xf2-^AE\x94\xb0\xa5\xf0\x83\xd11\xae3\xad\x9c\x0f\xb6\x05Da(ic;\xd0\xf7\xce~\xe3\xb2\x8c\xd4\x8e\xf7w_\xe8Ek\x1f\xf7\x92\xf3\xb7\xd8\xd5\x84\x07$\x7fm\x1c9i\xb6R2\xb9\x88*q\xa0\xde\xd3\x9e \xf7l}\xa1Oa\xe7\xb3\xbd\x92\x9a\xcd0\xb0\xa7\xc6a\xc8\xecQ\xaeR2{\xfc\x84~#\x8e\xf3\x1b{}w\xde\x9d\xd9\x10\xbf<\xf3\x8c\x12\x18\x906\xefa\x92)\x13\xd8b\x83\xdf\xfbN\x194\xf4E\x1d^\x06a{\x08\xac\x9co\xce\x04%\x1a\x0c\xb4\xad\x90\xfe\xdd*\x01\x82\xcfX\xeb\xe5\xb2}bm\xec^\xf6\xac!\xe8\xef\x84\x0eM\x1c\xb9\xd6\xd0\x04\x04\xcd\xf70\x83\xce\xa3\x16P\xc9\x0f\xc7/\xa0q+N\xe9.4\x19\xbbK\x1e\x8e.9WT6\xbc\x18\x1fU\xf9\xa3\x85\xd2^\xad&M\xf3\xc1\x893\xed\x0b\xa5\xaf\xc5f\n\xa73\xf4\xd0\tn;\x06\xf3\x81\x1b#R\xee\xca\x08g\x01J\xb8\x9e\xfb\xea\xe0\xb2\xc3\x8eWLG^]\x19\xdai\xc4\t\xdb\x84.k\x02&\xbe\t\x86m\x8e\x99#\x8a\x96\xb2\xa8\x10}G\xd8^\xc8\xae\xd6zZ\xbf!\xcfY\x17\xa4\xd8p\x80\x84e\x99\xfa\x15\x11\xd3\x05\x11\xbb\x83~:\xb9\xf2\xb55\xaa\x03\xd9\xcb\x1e\xccs\x95\xf9\x11^\xdb\xd63\x01\xd5.\x08\xa3\xec\xf5\x1e\xab\x94.\xfd\xe5 sO\x8a]PG\x8d\xcb\x87?*\n7_\xdd\xef\xba\x82\tp\xee{\x98X\x06\x7fD-\xd5=]\xa5\xbby\x1f\xba\xb5\x06M\xde~,\xd8\xc2\xac\xb7lP\xbe\t\x90\xdd\xc20\xd8G\xa3\x0b\xa2\x1ci\xdeX\xc7\x8ao\xb719\xac\xfa\xcb\x86Wk\xe6C54z\x90\xfb\x85\xa6\x06\xab\x9f\xfd\xbdR.\x15\x85\xaa\xb3\x17\xc9\'\xa6\n\x07\xfa\xef\xd9\xa7s.\xe9P\xb1\xff\xb3*\xe0\xe0\xa7\x85Q\x7f9\xc5E\'\xdd7\xd2\x9fn\x9c^\x99\xd3M\xef\xd7\xcc\xc6\xbe3}"\xb6\xf62\x13\x90\xe9\xd9\x18\xf5\xf9\xd1\x05\x14GC\x99\xeb\xd3\xda\xe4N\xaf\xa7\xee\x8e{vnN\xb5\xe0\x97\x95(\xc4\xbf\x7f6\xac\xfe\xf9E\xa5(\xa7\xaf\xf5\xf1\xd4\xd9gF[\xde\xc8Z]o\x93\xccFa.}q\x86\x00\xd9O\xc1\x9b,0\x9a(\x94\xcc_\x99\x9au4sR\xfd\x8c\xda\x99\x1d>\x99\xc1+\xb4\xd9J\xd7]\x81\x83g\x91+Y\x87\xb7 \x90F\x90\xed\xa2?\xdaZ#\xaa\xb9\xbc\xe3XWk\xf6\x97\xd6\x03\x19/\t\xc0\x8c$\x03\x93\xf13\xaa\x06\x06\x1d\xd9D\xc2\xbd\n\x9d,\x89\xae8f\xb7\x8a\x00\xad\x8a\xc4\xc4\xe4\x03\x9c\xcdYW\xb2E\xdc%-Nsy\\\xac\x8f\xed\xb1\x0e\x1dq\xdb\r\xac\xa4\xac5Y\xa1\x92\'\x99`\xcd\x86"\x98\x1c\xf7\x0e+\x95\\u\xfe\x177`\x9c\x9e\x83a\xdfr4?/\xffR?D\xe8\n\x19x\xb8\x17x\x93c>&*pL\xf6\x95\xea3\xfd\x06\x05c\xb6Z\xd8\xbd{\xc56S\xba\xf9\xd4\xa5\x0f\x90\x03\xc21d\x97Q\xae\x8cAS\x8d\x84Fr\xc7d\x7f\xc9\xa7\xae\xfbU\x94\xb1O\xf6\xbf\x11\xd2\x08\xc0\xc1)\t&KMq\x97\'\xa7\xd6F\xfdQa_\xf2\xdaZ\'\xad\'\xb2\xc5\xa3\x8f\xb0\xb5E\x85\x0f4\xed\x120\xea\x9f\xe2\xb8R\xfa-szD-\xcbM\xac\xbe\x80\xe1\x0b\xc5\xebiO\xba\x9f\x91{`\xa0\x15K\x87\xd5G\xd4\x16\xa4R\xc4\x9e\xfb\x99\xed\x9f,Iid\xe7\xe8:_\x19X\xb6\xf1}$L\x00\xd8\xce@\xfd\xe9\x06x\x01\xf3\xa1p\xf9@a\x9d#\xe3\x0buH\xf7H\xfc\xc5\xb5c\x03k%\xe6\x90\xfb\x9b\xbdJ\xd9\x7f\xb32\x16\xf3\xf0\xfd\xa7\xda\x8d\xbf*\xa8D\x0eo\x96r\xd921|$\xf9`\xf6V\x18\xf0\xd6\x95\xcb\xec\xcaUJT\xfcf\xfb\xf4\xea\xe3\xe8\x94\xe9u7\xf1\x96\xb6G\x8b\xc35\n\xbe\xf4>\x81\xc0\x10+F\xe7@\xa0@\x9eT\x1e\xf1\x82\xf7\xc7o\xfd_D\xbc\xda|\xaf\xc9\xf6\xb8x\xfe\xc64\x16\xc6\x017\xa0\xae\xc0\x9e\x95\x04Z6[o\xaa\x97Kn\xe9\xcc\xc9l\x8c\xde\xa4Rn\xa5kyON\x97\x07\x08\x19,\xa3ye\x91\x11\x99]\xcf\x9f\xaf\'\xd5R \xf4T\x8f\xf8\xc7\xa7\'\x8f\x9c\xd2\x15\xca\x08"#\xf7O\xea\xb6Z\x17t\x00J\x87rw\xabq\xc5\xcaq\xd5R\xae\x17\xddT\xb7b\xb4\xe0 \xfb"\x1e\xe8\xc4\x02\x9cJL\xe4\'\xaf\x0c\xd3h\x9d\x93\x1e\xa7\xd6\xa4\x07^\xae~Z\xb7\x7f6|T\xc1\x16\xc3\x03X\xc7!\x18\x9b46\x82\xe2\xf8\x1b\xbc\xa7u\x1d\x85<(\x8e\xd3\x11\'\x9d\xa4z/\xfa\x00\x1e\x07\xac\x8c+\xc7a_r]T\xf2M\xden\xe8b\xc5\xdf,M\xd3\x8d\xd5W\xba{\x85m\x99|\x03r\x05z\x04\x18C6\xe6%*\xa4%\xf0\xa6dN\x9cj\xf6\xb8!\xf9\xbcU8\x0e\xa7\xbf\x1d\xde\xdcE\x06xMd})\xaf\xe4\xdb8\xac\x8ch\xc7R\x17\xecv\x8b\x8e\xfd\x0b]&\xfa\x99\xeb\x1e\x16\xad\xee\x008\xb3~\x88l.\xd9n\x97\xacY\xa9Bad\xe4\xc6n\x1e\x06\x11\xab\x94o\xfa\xdcK=+\x83\xd4\x1f\xb3\x9dk\x82\x0c7\xf6Wp\xae\x9e3_\xbdI\xe8\xfd]\xa1\xc6\x02\x93\x92rE\xf8\xb2\x93\xf71\x1c\xc8rU\x0b!\xbb\xc4}v\xb1\x82*\x0fw\x8e\x8eX\x88\xa8\xa6\t\xea\xcam\xfex+\x9f\xd5\xa6\x84\xdc\xef\x1e\xe1\x8ad\xecv\xe4\xfcJ\x8d+\xbe\x8c\x94H\x93s\xf5=\xb4z\xb9\x05V}\x03\xfbC.\x0c\xf2=\xd4\xc8\xe4\x9d\xb3wU8\x04\xc5\xf4q\xafN\xd5\x0b_\xc4\xd8k\xb1\xba\xd7\xba\xf5Ee\xbdq\xc0~\xb3\x02L\x0e\x1a\x97\xcf\xe5lu\xf9\xc5+z\xd7\x8d}\xe8]\xb3\xe2\x92E\xf5\x83n(T%r~\x9c\xce\xc2d\xa7k\xd6\xe8\xa4|K\xf7\xf2\x9d\xc7\xf6g\xca\x0e=X&N\x99\x1aj\xf6\xe8pC\xf2\xb7\x008\xb2\x0co\xf5\xba\x0c\xd6\x03O\xcfMi\x0e\x97\x85\xe0I\\\xbd\xec`\x91\x06\x91\xf1\xb2\x0f\xe8\x11\xa50d\xa7W\xdb\xb2\x92\x8ea\x85R25\x8a\xe6\x9d\xb5\xec\xa9*\xee\xa4^mg\xa8\x9f\x0c\\\x9d\xce*\x92\xd5\xf8\x95\xc2\x03\x15a\x0f\xdb+J:[\xbfH\xd7\x02\x19\xf5\xc2\xfa9\xfd\xd3W \xc0\xdc\xadB&\xd3\xc3.\x19p\xaa\xe6\x99\xde\xaf\x84\x13\xa9\x9dY+\xad\xe1|\xef\x07\xcaM\xde6L\xe0\x10\xa8\x8a\xd4\xc7\t\xaeRZB\xca\xa7\xae\xa9Ck\xea\xb8iU(\x9e\x88m:\xdfa?\xbf\x03\x90\x0350\x14\xde\x03\xa4>V\x15\xa6^ffq\x1aL[\xd4m\x132UOK\xd3\x125\x91\xf9sO\xc5\x04\xd9=\xe7\xca\xa4\xf9\xdb5\xbc\xae\xbbp\xfa\r\xce\xc7k\x94\x1c\x92\xfc\x8b\xb4\xb7\x19\x84\xf4\xf7\x08\xc3\xd0\x04f*\xc59\xf7B?j\x85\xd0\x8a\xf6\xdbZr\x95_\xd1Vt\x12\x04\xab\xbe\xf1\x00\x91\xb0\x13\xa6\x89\xd3+E\x93Q\xd86\x91\xb2z\xc1\x19)\xb6\x03:;Q\x07\x12\xaf\x13Y\x8d\x07\xda \x14\xa6\x89l\x0f\x102\x18\xf3\xdcu\xad\xee\xa6\xfbxV\xe8\xbeF\xc7\x08\xd3\xd6\xb5\xb6\xae\xbf\xbb\x02\xe1\xed1Lf\x96\xc0;\xe9\xe2{COj\xa7\x1c%\xad\xb2\xe9\xc7V].\'\xcc\x0eX\x1e\xc2\x10\x00#\xc9\x03\xe3\xd8\xd8\x1cp\xb8\xc7\x93s+\xc2G\xf7Vu\xb8\xf9\x1b\x82\xf3\xeb\x99\xa9\x86C\xb5\xb3L@r\xd3\xc6P2\xc3\x12\x95\xf4\x17tm\x04$\x9c\x9a9\x04\xdfC\xa1[\xe4}\xae\xdbS\xe52\\\x01\x99\xa0\xe5M1\xe0/\xa02\xd8\x92\xa5\xf1\xbd95\xfb\xce\x18*\xbc,8\x90\xda\xa7\x1b%\x94_\x05pn\xaaH\xfd\x1f\r\x10O\xee\x98\xa9\x97v\x94\x8e\xc5)&\xff\x9a\xd2\xf7@\xe6\x89\xb6\xdf\x1fE<`FT\x83\xc9\x14\xa4\xbf~\x9f\xd8\xca\xe9:\xe6\x13\x87\x80\x1d[.9\x07\x96\xde7*\xd9\x85\xc4\xaf\xe7A\x87\xc9\n\x1f\x13\xa1\x87\x04\x89\xb1\xce:\xbd7\x1b\'\x8d\xd2\x82\xf3\xda{DZ\x8dZ\xeb]\x01\xce\x9a\x0e\x9b\xfb \xe7;%\xb9\xbf\x96\xd5\x11\x7fG\x81\xf0PG\xb0)\xb6\xc6T\xa1\x04\xcfa\x02\x99X\x7fE\xc7\x12\xb3^\x93a\xf6\xb3\xc2\xb6\xba\xbc\xd8\xc9\xa1\xf9\x16\x8aM\xfd\x8d\xed\x15^C\x93\xc8\xfb\xc1\x8a\xaeh\xee1\'\xbf?\xb59 \xe2\xf3[\xd6=I`1\xe2i?\x1f}i=\xfbwS<\x90\xb7K\x80\xc9[\x1c+\xa1!T\xd1\xb7\xd3\xaeq\xe2IX\xb3*!\xbd\x0f!\xa7|7(\x91\xf1@\xaf\xcb7\xc4i\xf5\x15\xeb\r\xd5\xe3\xb1\xa4w+n8\x0c\xe7\x9d\xcfR\xbd\xee\xbe\xedM\xd3W\xb1\xfb|`G\xd4\x86)\xfb?p\xc5\xd3\xc8W/\xa6\xd6\xa5\x05\xa9\xae*\x01\xd5R\x1fo\xef\xa9\xe1\xe9^\xe7-\xd6\'\x0c\xe5\xfc\x8c\xfc\xd1T\xa9/\x1b{\x8e\xe1\xc3B&\x9a\xb4r\xfdV\xb9\x84\x06&\xb4f\xe5\x03\x12\xbd\x00\x13\xb4\xd1eA<\xcd\xcd5\x7f\xdb\xb5\x99^\xd9\xae\x14\xb2SH:\xf3\xd1\x0c\xa7-\xa3\x03\x10\x03t0\xb4e\xfc\x00\x15N\x94\xd4[tVT\x7f\xcc\x93F}_\xe12\x93N\xfaUw%\x18`\x03u\xbci\x02!H\xfda%\xd6-t\xf5\xeb\xf1D\x1e\xd8\r\x04e\x15D\xb0\xea\xb9\t\x10P\xf6\xf4\x85\xa9u\xdb\x91\xfb\xff\xf8\x1b\x03\xe5\xb2\xc0\xab\xe8\xe8X\xbf\xf48\x98\xbe\xdczg4\x8c\xbco\x19\xd90\xa5\'\xc7z9\xca\x8d`8}\xeav\xc0Ql\xc3{t\xd4\xfd\x9a$\xff\x8f2\xe7q@\xda\'\x08G~\x81\xfa}\x7f\x8a\xb4x)we~\xb5\xb2\xea\xfevh\x8d\xdb\xa5\x84x\xd7Y%\x08Hd\xa8\xc1W^\xa3+Q\\4\xaa>\xab\xf0C\xe2\xd3U"W\x92\x07rU\x9d\x0e\x06\x15g@\x80\xe8\xb8\xc3\xe8\xceq(~\x0bn\xfd\xdc\xa7\xc2\xdc#S\x98\x0b7\x9d\x0f\x8a\xf8\x86\xf7\r\x9d\xb92\xd0\x01\x1eg\xe8\xc8}=\x0fq\xa1\xdf\xae\x8eii\xb5\xe7\x9aZ\xcd\xf9\xa8MP,\xe9j\xb9\x1f\x96\x7f$\x00\x9e\xb7\x97\xae\x92\x90\x88\xaf\x9d\xe4\xd7\x9e\x15O\x8e\x9f7g\x8e\xb7$=$\xb4\xf4\x04\xde\x89\xc3\xc6s\x00iO\x92|o\xa5\xe2\xb6RQ\xa2\xf4\x14K~O9\x9f\x00\xd6\x16\xed\xdc*u\xe0\xd4\xad\xd7AM@\xc4\x9b\x8auL\x14\xc5\xa2D\nWU\x9b\xd5\xd7\xdc\x0c\x88r\xb3\xb0~\xf9B\'\xfd`\xc4J\x93>\x80{\xa2\x8d\xbd\xfc^ \x00\xa5\xd7<\xf3h\x9f\x95S\x8a\xd8\xbc\x7f\x89\xd9\r\xe6\x91\x8f6\xd5J\x19M`\xc4\x97\xc6\xa6:K\'\xa2\x8c\x870B\x16\xc3\xcf\xa3J\x96Ow\xa8\xbdQA{\xcdm4\xdb\xd4\x01H\x1ez\xca\x9f\xdf.O\x84r\x08\xb8\xf8\xe6\xd9\xf1Ib\xc2\x85\n7\xec \xf1\x8f9Y\xd5W\xc8\xf9H\xdc)\xce\xe0)rQG\xf7\xd6y\xaa\xef\x1b\x19\xf3\re\xcc\xd0\xd7\x1e\t\x7f\x92p\xfdi1\x0ey_%\xb8\xb9\x0fI/\xa0N\x9d\x9d\x1dpM\xc3_do<\x9f\xbe\xdap\xce\xaa\xebk\xfb\xbex<\xe0\xb1\xc2\xd84\xa2h"\n\xf7t\xf9&\x93\xe6m\x98\xe1\xea9R\xd3\x0e\xb3\xe7jm\x9b\xb8\xaa<\xe0\xb6!Z\xdd9\x1e\xd5\xe3\x9fzv\xb6\xe5\xc5\xca@KL@\x7f\xf8pd\xe7\xe6@\x9d\xc9\x81\x1a\x1e %\x19\xa9\xbf6\xcc\xb6\x86\xfa\xb4\xeb\xf5m\x0b\xbd\n\xee\xd6g==\xc3O\x18\xd3:hF2s\x05f\xfe\x9c\xe8\xf6vh\x01zr\xbf\xfb\xed\xa1\xc0\xb4\xb6\xfb\xb0\xce\xf8\xda\x96\xfbk9\x86\x93!k\x90\xfa\xfd$F\xfd\xc2nT"T![\r\xca\xa7\xeb\x18\xb3\xc2\xc7\xf9\xf2!\xa8IaSt\xf1;d\xfei\xabb\xc2\x1c\x90\xf7-\x9dE\xf7\xde\xb16\x85/X\x00u\x0b=\xa0;\x1d6\xb0}\xcbl\x02<k\x86\xba\xb3\xb2(\x16\xaa\xdcPe{\xf9k\xb2`\xe6J\xfb\xcf\x1fh\x0f*\x1f\xff:k^\x05\x03\xe2\x9b\xb8\xa8\xd2#\xa8J(\xe6\x8d\x89\xeb\x96\x9e\xfdo>\x1f\xfdbmQ\x16UE\x95\xf9%\xed\x03\x0c\xf46P7~:\'\xa9l\'E\x88\xce>\x1b\xf1\x9au\x87\xf9f~\xa8\xc2\xc1\xc4p@\xac\xfa\x1c\x0e\xf0ZuW\xec\xb8\xb1\xec\x88\xe6\xe4\xfb-\xb6\xba:bg\xeeo_\x87)\xa2q\x85C\xe4\xe6\xfd\x0e\xe1\x00\x89\x19\x81\xa5\xbc\x10\x18\x81:\xe6&f\xce>\xf6\xce\xd3-\x1e\xc0\xc9.;*,2\xf1\x18\xe86\x01\xe5\x8bA\xaa\xdbL`.$P\x98,w\xad%\xe7\xfeN\xf9x\x85\x82\xc1h\xd0a!00\xcb\x03\xbc\x90\xa0\x15V6\x82\xd6\x90\x8f\xf4\x17\xbb\x13\xa4\x97\x05\x8c\xact\xcf\xa4\x0f7\xf2\x12Z\x06\x83N\xe7\x83\xfeST\x85\x9d\x8d\xc9\xe1\x8azW17x\xe7\xfd\xb3\x85W\x1c\x7f\x1b\xe2\xab&r\x13p\xacf\x91\xf9\x0b\x89\xd5\x9d\xd3\xb3\xcf\x93\x928\xd4\xe8\r\x9e\xd6\xe8L\xacR:q\xd8et\xe0\xb4\x88&\xf77<0\xf3\xa5\xab\xef\xd6\x83}\xed\xd2M\xbcV\xdf\xb5)b\x14GD\x9eU\xb7\xc8\xb9t\xf1\xc0\xc9V\x0c2\x7f\x9e\xc7\x0c\xce4\t^\xd2\xca\x16\xa8\xdf+\xe4\x9f\xc0\x98-^\x96\xbb\xdd\xc1\xe6D\xcdj#\xbaJ\x1f\x18a\xc5\xc8o\xe2\xa6\x9f/\xcd\x0b[q\xe3\x9a[\xf7DE\xed(\x17\xeb\x12\xea\x15L%\x9bG\xe3\x01\xc6Y\xc3h\xf39U+\x92>j\xe3\xb9\x86\xcd\xd2\xc2n=B\x17\xac\xc8GI\x18\xfd\xde?\xa8\xae\xc0-l\x8f\x02A\xc2i\x8b)\xfd\xe1\xea\xa3O)\xfa\x12\xaf|F\x98\xc0\x04\xae\x1eoV>\xdd@\x06\xd8x\xbaA\x02K\xcaj\xdb\xed\xb3|\x96\x97\xb2E\x97\x83\xd4\xd6_\'^\xde\xb8u\x9bx7\'\xbc\n\x8c8g*<S>W\t\x05\x9d\xf3\x18\xb7\xfeUcx\xe6\xeb\xf5\xd8\xf8\xdb>E\xac\xe4[\xdejH\xfc,\xfaF/g\x07\xd1mBW+#\xf6e:\x82;\xd3o\xb0,\xaf\xafv5%\xf6,\'>x\xe1\x12\x1a3\xf7I\x8b\x8b\xf2\xf5\xc0k%\x9e\xb8\xec\xd9T\xabC\x8c0\xdanY\xdcpn\xea!\x0c0\xd1\xfd\xba\xf9\xc7\xc5\xac!K\x8d[\xe2\xdb\xde\xcb\xa9*J\x08g\xa7\xbeqrV\x1e\xe8\'\x0f6!\xfb_\x07;I\x95-\xda\xa7_sd\xecC\xdf\xf2\x8f\xe6\xa8\xf8\xf5x\x8bP+k\xc13\x1aU}\x80\x17\x8b]q\xf1\x88\x04\x16ePxX6]%;\x94y\xe6\x19Y}=_b\x9dI\xcb\xc4\x0e\x02\xf0\x08HP\xe0\xa6@\x0b\xa8\xbd5}\'\xa2\x1c\x85\x92.N\xbe3\xbb\xfcV&\x82\x1d\x18\xbc&\xbd\x03<\xf7\xd5\x8e\x99\x17N}\x07G\xdfs\x9ei\x18\xde\xbc^\xdf;w\xbe\xb2\x98\x9a:\xd6s]C\x01\x19?,H}\\\x0f\xe3\x02\xbb\xcc\x1e\xb1=v8I\xe1\xf6\xe8\x99\xdf\xc4\x1b\x1d4\xf69ds4\x90\xfc}\xb5\xb16\xfa\xf0\x02\xcaBu\xaf\x8c\x9a\xe7BV}|~\xd9\x87\xce\xe3\xfbv]<M\xc64\xfd\x7f\xfc\x13\xb4\x84%,a\tK\xf8\x0f\xe1\x1f\xf8\x0eLo\x00&\x00\x00'
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to unzip the content, and you can use the `gzip` module to do this. Use [`gzip.decompress`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/gzip.html#gzip.decompress) to read the content into a wav file:

```py
import requests
import gzip

r = requests.get(url = urll, headers = hederr, stream=True)

with open('myfile.wav', 'wb') as fh:
    fh.write(gzip.decompress(r.content))
```

### Edit

Since this is apparently a `wav.tar.gz` file, you'll want to un-tar the decompressed content:

```py
import requests
import gzip
import tarfile
from io import BytesIO

r = requests.get(url = urll, headers = hederr, stream=True)

with open('myfile.wav.tar', 'wb') as fh:
    fh.write(gzip.decompress(r.content))

with tarfile.open('myfile.wav.tar', 'rb') as fh:
    fh.extractall()
```

Where `extractall` will extract to the current working directory by default, but you can specify a separate directory if you want via `fh.extractall(path='/some/path')`. To avoid intermediate files, you could do:

```py
with BytesIO(gzip.decompress(r.content)) as fh:
    tf = tarfile.TarFile(fileobj=fh)
    tf.extractall()
```

Comment: I tried this and now the file is converting as tar not as  ".wav"

Comment: So it's a `wav.tar.gz`?

Comment: yes it's ```wav.tar.gz``` bytes.  how can I convert into .wav